# Cannot execute binary in Linux?

Tags: centos

I'm trying to download / execute the Centos 5 64bit auto installer:

http://www.parallels.com/download/sitebuilder4/#CENTOS5X86_64

http://download1.parallels.com/SiteBuilder/4.5.0/autoinstaller/parallels_installer_v3.3.2_build080710.09_os_CentOS_5_x86_64

Once obtained, how do I run that script?

```
root@server [~]# wget http://download1.parallels.com/SiteBuilder/4.5.0/autoinstaller/parallels_installer_v3.3.2_build080710.09_os_CentOS_5_x86_64
--12:39:13--  http://download1.parallels.com/SiteBuilder/4.5.0/autoinstaller/parallels_installer_v3.3.2_build080710.09_os_CentOS_5_x86_64
           => `parallels_installer_v3.3.2_build080710.09_os_CentOS_5_x86_64'
Resolving download1.parallels.com... 72.21.81.63
Connecting to download1.parallels.com|72.21.81.63|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3,374,848 (3.2M) [text/plain]

100%[====================================================================================================================================================================================================================>] 3,374,848      2.69M/s             

12:39:14 (2.68 MB/s) - `parallels_installer_v3.3.2_build080710.09_os_CentOS_5_x86_64' saved [3374848/3374848]

root@server [~]# chmod +x parallels_installer_v3.3.2_build080710.09_os_CentOS_5_x86_64

root@server [~]# sh parallels_installer_v3.3.2_build080710.09_os_CentOS_5_x86_64
parallels_installer_v3.3.2_build080710.09_os_CentOS_5_x86_64: parallels_installer_v3.3.2_build080710.09_os_CentOS_5_x86_64: cannot execute binary file
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to run it using `./executablefilename` instead of using `sh executablefilename`. It's not a shell script after all.

Comment: Also make sure the executable's architecture (in this case x86_64) is compatible with your OS's architecture in case you didn't get it to run with Mario's advice.